# Hide a machine on LAN

Tags: network, anonymity, vlans

Is there any way to hide a computer on LAN? For example maybe with a firewall, when someone is going to ping a machine, it won't answer. In other words the machine must answer to router only.

I am the network administrator. The switch hasn't VLAN. I use Linux (Debian)

My topology is this one:

[image: topology]

Comment: Is your intention to have machines connected to your wireless access point be segregated from your network but still have internet access?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about network configuration, which belongs on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com) or [Network Engineering](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Anonymity is however in my opinion an important aspect of Information Security.

Comment: My intention is to connect to switch. An internet connection would be good if there is a way I would like to learn it. Or without internet

Comment: What do you mean by “hide”? If you want your machine not to respond to ping (which is usually a bad idea), just configure it not to do that.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26779/the-best-way-to-hide-my-computer-on-a-network) answer you can deny all incoming connections using `iptables -p INPUT DROP` as following:

```
iptables -I INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
iptables -p INPUT DROP
```

All **incoming** attempts to connect to your computer fails and **only** connections initiated by your computer works. So your machine won't respond to pings.

However you are still broadcasting [ARP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol) packets and connected to the router. You can't disable ARP requests because if you do you won't be able to use the network. So basically it is still visible according to this scenario.

Comment: So the only packets will be seen from my machine is ARP, this is good.My users use windows and the check the Network menu on windows, from file manager, I think the Linux machine wont be there.

Comment: @S.I.Tsaklidis You could even give it a static ARP entry so no such traffic would appear.

Comment: You could probably firewall up to the point where it'll only *respond* to ARP requests when they come from the router, but yeah -- it'd still broadcast ARP *requests*.